# Good in-memory size of ArrayList of ParseObject on android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a subclass of ParseObject with 13 `public static String` members, 30 getters and setters combined and three other methods.

@ParseClassName("Mine")
public class Mine extends ParseObject{
  ...
}

**How many of these objects is reasonable to keep in memory in an ArrayList for an android adapter?**

```
ArrayList<Mine> mineList;//size 30? 300? 1000?
```

What if one of my getters returned a bitmap loaded from a ParseFile? as in

```
Bitmap getBitmap(String parseFilekey){
  ParseFile file = getParseFile(parseFileKey);
  return getBitmap(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably something you'll have to benchmark yourself using the tools that come with Android Studio.

You can create a few tests where you load your objects into your `ArrayList`, and then you'll have to keep an eye on memory consumption and other relevant data.

As from the docs, Memory Monitor is good for:

> - Showing available and used memory in a graph, and garbage collection    events over time.
> - Quickly testing whether app slowness might be related to excessive    garbage collection events.
> - **Quickly testing whether app crashes may be related to running out of    memory.**

Otherwise I don't think we can give you a precise answer.

Here's an image on Android Studios Memory Monitor.

[image: Memory Monitor]

You can read on how to use it here on [this link](https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html).

**P.S.:** Keep in mind that this answer *depends on what device you're using, and how much RAM the phone have*.